# Spectral radius of a block matrix with a block that has spectral radius larger than 1

Tags: matrices, dynamical-systems, block-matrices, spectral-radius

Suppose we have a $n\times n$ block matrix

$$
X=
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} &  \ldots & A_{1n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
A_{n1} & \ldots & A_{nn}
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where each block $A_{ij}$ is $d_i\times d_j$ and the diagonal blocks $A_{ii}$ are symmetric.

If there exists a block $A_{ii}$ such that $\rho(A_{ii})>1$, can we say anything about $\rho(X)$, for example, $\rho(X)>1$?

For instance, we could think of $X$ as a Jacobian matrix of a vector field that describes a $n$-player optimization dynamics. My conjecture is that the overall dynamics would be unstable, $\rho(X)>1$, if there is a player who is unstable under its own optimization dynamics, $\rho(A_{ii})>1$.

Comment: In the context of Jacobian and triangular matrices, a single eigenvalue greater than 1 for a diagonal block will remain an eigenvalue for the whole matrix. But I'm pretty sure there is no such result in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search with math software gave me several counterexamples:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0. & -0.3 \\ 0.8 & 1.1\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \lambda=0.8, 0.3$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}1.2 & -1 & 0.3 \\
 0 & 0 & -0.3 \\
 -1 & 0.5 & -0.5\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \lambda=0.643, 0.461, -0.404$$

One can imagine replacing each number by a block matrix of the same order of magnitude (e.g. $a\mapsto aI$) and the results should still hold.

In the context of dynamics, one variable -- the prey -- may increase exponentially if isolated, but the other variables -- the predators -- may restrict it from growing.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. This is quite a bit disappointing though. Do you have any idea on additional conditions for the blocks $A_{ij}$ which would make $\rho(X)>1$?

Comment: @June Yes, there's [Gershgorin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem): An eigenvalue is as far from a diagonal term as the sum of the other terms in the same row. So if a diagonal term (or block) is sufficiently large to 'dominate' its row, then 'its' eigenvalue is assured to be near it, hence larger than $1$.

Comment: I was exactly looking at the theorem. So, intuitively, unstable local dynamics $A_{ii}$ of a player $i$ would imply instability of overall dynamics when there is relatively little interaction between players. Thanks again!

Comment: @June Agreed. That's only one case though. There may be lots of interaction, but if a player's dynamics is punished sufficiently, the instability may remain bounded.